# Command similar to Linux's 'clear' in Windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Is there any command available in Windows command prompt which has the same effect as 'clear' in Linux terminal? That means ability to clear the command window from outputs of previous executions. In case there is not such command, how I can clear the command window?

Comment: If any of the answer solves your question then please feel free to mark as accepted. Some new comers forget to accept any answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Type **`cls`**.
- **`cls`**  command will erase all text from the screen and display an empty prompt at the top of the screen.

[image]

- Just incase you want to see other commands then type ***`help`*** command

Comment: cle was an instruction from BASIC interpreter. Yeah, it does just that, clearing the display.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is [**`cls`**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cls.mspx?mfr=true).

> Clears the Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell `Clear-Host` function or its aliases `cls`,`clear` all would work.